# How to disable all global hotkeys in KDE Plasma?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, i3, kubuntu, plasma5

I'm using a `KDE+i3` setup on my machine and therefore I want to disable all the global hotkeys provided by KDE, since I've binded the keys properly in my i3-config.
Upon exploring `qdbus` API, I've found out the command works per Plasma session:

```
qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /kglobalaccel blockGlobalShortcuts true
```

### Issues

The issue is how to begin with its automation. The following are the issues:

- Global keys start working again after *Sleep*, *Lock* etc. which restart Plasma.
- I've used

  ```
  exec --no-startup-id qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /kglobalaccel \
  blockGlobalShortcuts true
  ```

  for now but only works till Plasma doesn't restart.

How should I proceed with implementing this?

Comment: Also, it would be better if the solution would be implemented by i3wm since I'm planning to keep my Plasma Xsession untouched.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a way to disable all the global shortcuts of KDE. Here's what I did:

- The hotkeys are saved in `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc` in the form of `foo=bar` assignments.
- Using `sed`, replace the hotkeys.
- Restart `kglobalaccel` to observe the changes.

Here's the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

hotkeysRC="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/kglobalshortcutsrc"

# Remove application launching shortcuts.
sed -i 's/_launch=[^,]*/_launch=none/g' $hotkeysRC

# Remove other global shortcuts.
sed -i 's/^\([^_].*\)=[^,]*/\1=none/g' $hotkeysRC

# Reload hotkeys.
kquitapp5 kglobalaccel && sleep 2s && kglobalaccel5 &
```

Now I can finally move all of my key bindings to i3 config!

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified the script by Utkarsh since it didn't work for my installation (probably syntax in kglobalshortcutsrc has changed):

```
#!/bin/sh

fl="$HOME/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc"

sed -i 's/=.*,.*,/=none,none,/g' $fl
sed -i 's/Walk Through Windows=.*/Walk Through Windows=Alt+Tab,Alt+Tab,Walk Through Windows/' $fl # return alt+tab

# Reload hotkeys.
kquitapp5 kglobalaccel && sleep 2s && kglobalaccel5 &
```